# Python Globbing a directory of images

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I am working on a project currently and so far I have generated a folder of images (png format) where I need to iterate through each image and do some operation on it using PIL.

I have the operation correctly working by manually linking the file path into the script. 
To iterate through each image I tried using the following

```
frames = glob.glob("*.png")
```

But this yields a list of the filenames as strings.

PIL requires a filepath for the image to be loaded and thus further used

```
filename = input("file path:")
image = Image.open(filename)
callimage = image.load()
```

How can I convert the strings from the glob.glob list and have it used as an argument for the Image.open method?

Thanks for your feedback!

I am on python 3.6.1 if that holds any relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with `os` package:

```
import os

source_path = "my_path"

image_files = [os.path.join(base_path, f) for f in files for base_path, _, files in os.walk(source_path) if f.endswith(".png")]

for filepath in image_files:
    callimage = Image.open(filepath).load()
    # ...
```

Solution using `glob`:

```
import glob

source_path = "my_path"

image_files = [source_path + '/' + f for f in glob.glob('*.png')]

for filepath in image_files:
    callimage = Image.open(filepath).load()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pathlib` library instead of `glob.glob()` so that you don't have to worry about building the file's path. The `Image.open()` method also takes a `pathlib.Path` object as the first argument.

```
from pathlib import Path

frames = Path('path_to_folder')

for file in frames.glob('*.png'):
    callimage = Image.open(file).load()
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin `map()` is a general way to do something, in this case `load`, for a list of things: 
`map( func, [a, b, c ...] )` is roughly
`[func(a), func(b), func(c) ...]`.
So

```
def loadit( png ): 
    return Image.open( png ).load()

images = map( loadit, glob( "*.png" ))
for image in images: ...
```

This [functional](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/functional.html)
style is worth learning;
it fits well with flow diagrams on paper.

(Fine print: `print( list( map( ... )))`, not `print( map( ... ))`.)