# How can I read folder-wise all images then after processing the images, how can I store these in another folder using OPEN CV in google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, google-colaboratory, opencv, python

I want to apply some image processing operation on chest x-ray images using google colab platform with python open cv. But for the processing of the images I faced troubled to process the whole folder images and save it to new folder. I can process single image easily but can't find any way how to process all the images folderwise and save these to another folder.

Comment: you can get list of all files using  `glob` library like `file_list = glob.glob(*.jpg)` and then process them by iterating with `for image in file_list:` and afterwards you can copy the files to other folder with `shutil.copy()`

Comment: Thank you, can you kindly provide me the explanation in code format I am a pretty beginner in this field.

Comment: @MonzilAhamed see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434987/)