# read multiple images files in a folder for data augmentation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, glob

Can't seem to read my image files into jupyter notebook.

code looks like this + output

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
from skimage import io

file_list = glob.glob(
    r'images\*.*'
)

print(file_list)
```

output : []

```
my_list =[]

for file in file_list:
    im = io.read(file)
    my_list.append(im)
```

```
my_list
```

output : []

Comment: Hi, your `file_list` is empty, so the rest fails and this has nothing to do with any of the tags you provide. The question is what system are you using? What images are you loading and is your path correct? What is the output of `os.listdir('./images')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Globbing a directory of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434091/python-globbing-a-directory-of-images)

Comment: Thanks for commenting. ```FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './images'```

I am trying to read in 65 png images

Comment: can you, instead of the `./` add your full path to the images? Ie. `os.listdir('full_path_to_this_folder/images')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Path.glob to get the list of files, Pathlib handles Path for all the  Operating Systems

```
from pathlib import Path

file_list = sorted(Path('./images').glob('*.*'))
```